# Why Composite Operation in SVG is not working?

Tags: svg, composite

I am trying to develop composite operation in SVG. I found below code to implement composite operation in svg but while I am applying same example I am not getting composite operation in output. I have try this code to test in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io) and getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ2qk.png) output. and my desire output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQcW3.png)

I found this example code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feComposite)

```html
<svg width="330" height="195" viewBox="0 0 1100 650" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Example feComposite - Examples of feComposite operations</title>
  <desc>Four rows of six pairs of overlapping triangles depicting
        the six different feComposite operators under different
        opacity values and different clearing of the background.</desc>
 <defs>
    <desc>Define two sets of six filters for each of the six compositing operators.
          The first set wipes out the background image by flooding with opaque white.
          The second set does not wipe out the background, with the result
          that the background sometimes shines through and is other cases
          is blended into itself (i.e., "double-counting").</desc>
    <filter id="overFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="over" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="inFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="in" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="outFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="out" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="atopFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="atop" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="xorFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="xor" result="comp"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="arithmeticFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
            x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" result="comp"
                   operator="arithmetic" k1=".5" k2=".5" k3=".5" k4=".5"/>
      <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="flood"/> <feMergeNode in="comp"/> </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <filter id="overNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="over" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="inNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="in" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="outNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="out" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="atopNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="atop" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="xorNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" operator="xor" result="comp"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="arithmeticNoFlood" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
            x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImage" result="comp"
                   operator="arithmetic" k1=".5" k2=".5" k3=".5" k4=".5"/>
    </filter>
    <path id="Blue100" d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 z" fill="#00ffff" />
    <path id="Red100" d="M 0 0 L 0 100 L 100 0 z" fill="#ff00ff" />
    <path id="Blue50" d="M 0 125 L 100 125 L 100 225 z" fill="#00ffff" fill-opacity=".5" />
    <path id="Red50" d="M 0 125 L 0 225 L 100 125 z" fill="#ff00ff" fill-opacity=".5" />
    <g id="TwoBlueTriangles">
      <use xlink:href="#Blue100"/>
      <use xlink:href="#Blue50"/>
    </g>
    <g id="BlueTriangles">
      <use transform="translate(275,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(400,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(525,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(650,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(775,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
      <use transform="translate(900,25)" xlink:href="#TwoBlueTriangles"/>
    </g>
  </defs>

  <rect fill="none" stroke="blue" x="1" y="1" width="1098" height="648"/>
  <g font-family="Verdana" font-size="40" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <desc>Render the examples using the filters that draw on top of
          an opaque white surface, thus obliterating the background.</desc>
    <g enable-background="new">
      <text x="15" y="75">opacity 1.0</text>
      <text x="15" y="115" font-size="27">(with feFlood)</text>
      <text x="15" y="200">opacity 0.5</text>
      <text x="15" y="240" font-size="27">(with feFlood)</text>
      <use xlink:href="#BlueTriangles"/>
      <g transform="translate(275,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#overFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#overFlood)" />
        <text x="5" y="275">over</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(400,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#inFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#inFlood)" />
        <text x="35" y="275">in</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(525,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#outFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#outFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">out</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(650,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#atopFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#atopFlood)" />
        <text x="10" y="275">atop</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(775,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#xorFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#xorFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">xor</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(900,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#arithmeticFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#arithmeticFlood)" />
        <text x="-25" y="275">arithmetic</text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0,325)" enable-background="new">
    <desc>Render the examples using the filters that do not obliterate
          the background, thus sometimes causing the background to continue
          to appear in some cases, and in other cases the background
          image blends into itself ("double-counting").</desc>
      <text x="15" y="75">opacity 1.0</text>
      <text x="15" y="115" font-size="27">(without feFlood)</text>
      <text x="15" y="200">opacity 0.5</text>
      <text x="15" y="240" font-size="27">(without feFlood)</text>
      <use xlink:href="#BlueTriangles"/>
      <g transform="translate(275,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#overNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#overNoFlood)" />
        <text x="5" y="275">over</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(400,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#inNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#inNoFlood)" />
        <text x="35" y="275">in</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(525,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#outNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#outNoFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">out</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(650,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#atopNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#atopNoFlood)" />
        <text x="10" y="275">atop</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(775,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#xorNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#xorNoFlood)" />
        <text x="15" y="275">xor</text>
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(900,25)">
        <use xlink:href="#Red100" filter="url(#arithmeticNoFlood)" />
        <use xlink:href="#Red50" filter="url(#arithmeticNoFlood)" />
        <text x="-25" y="275">arithmetic</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I found one more code which is also not working for composite operation. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay3dy.png) is desire output of below code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="simplecompop"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 480 360">
     <title>Simple Compositing</title>
     <g id="content">
        <circle cx="200" cy="160" r="50" fill="blue" opacity="0.7"/>
        <rect x="180" y="150" width="160" height="100" fill="red" opacity="0.8" comp-op="src-atop"/>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure if this is what you are expecting. This is my solution: I'm creating a filter where I'm using a flooded rectangle for the `in` attribute and the source graphic for the `in2` attribute. The operator I'm using is `atop` as you intended.

```html
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="simplecompop"
    viewBox="0 100 480 360">
     <title>Simple Compositing</title>
  
    <filter id="f" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feFlood x="180" y="150" width="160" height="100" flood-color="red" flood-opacity="0.7" result="img1"></feFlood>
    <feComposite in="img1" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="atop"></feComposite>
  </filter>
     <g id="content">
        <circle cx="200" cy="160" r="50" fill="blue" opacity="0.8" style="filter: url(#f)"/>
     </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, it's helpful.@enxaneta